# What does share operator do in RxJava? When should I use it?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java2, reactivex

I know that share() is a replacement of publish().refCount(). 
Then from the RxJava wiki:

> Observable.publish( ) — represents an Observable as a Connectable Observable
>   ConnectableObservable.refCount( ) — makes a Connectable Observable behave like an ordinary Observable

This make me confused. If after publish().refCount(), it just behave like an ordinary Observable, why should I use it, how does this api make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right - `Observable.share` is just a shortcut for `publish().refCount()`. I think that description you have quoted above is not entirely clear as `ConnectedObservable.refCount` does a little bit more :)

If you transform your `Observable` to `ConnectableObservable` - it will not emit items (even if something is subscribed) unless explicitly called `ConnectableObservable.connect` - it basically defers execution of `subscribe` method and prevents from executing it multiple times for every subscriber. This technique is often used to make sure that all subscribers are subscribed before observable starts emitting items (in other words - after everyone has subscribed - `connect()` method is called).

If you have more than one subscriber (what often happens), you have to handle their subscriptions and unsubscriptions and this is where things are getting tricky. This is why `refCount()` was introduced. This operator returns new Observable, keeps track of how many subscribers are subscribed to it and stays connected as long as there is at least one subscription. It will also automatically connect when the first subscriber appears.

PS. I'm learning how to use RxJava, if I am wrong - please point it out!

Comment: Thank you for your explaination, I knew the meaning of publish and refCount, but just didn't understand why they are used together.

Comment: @WooguxWu They are used together because there's no other way to achieve behaviour of `refCount` without `publish`. It's not true that after `publish().refCount()` all you get is an ordinary Observable - or.. at least it's not the same Observable as before applying these operators :). Its behaviour is affected by these operators.

Comment: Yeah, I know it must be different, I just want to know what is different. Is that just like refCount()? But if it is not connectable before share, then how does refCount affect()?

Comment: @WooguxWu - it must be connectable in order to call `refCount` as `refCount()` is a method of `ConnectableObservable` interface.

Comment: Sorry, my English is terrible. What I mean is that: what is the difference between the Observable before share and the Observable after share?

Comment: @WooguxWu after you use `share()`, resulting Observable will start emiting events right after first subscription and following subscriptions will not trigger again `Observable.subscribe` method of your Observable. Only after all subscibers are unsubscribed from this Observable - it will be disposed. This is something different from regular Observable created by f.e. `Observable.just` as in this case each subscription would result in calling `Observable.subscribe`. And each unsubscription would cause its very subscription to dispose - however wierd it sounds :)

Comment: It would be the easiest if you just created simple project with RxJava and tried it yourself. Create observable using `Observable.create`, put some printing and sleeps there and see how it behaves with and without `share()` when having multiple subscriptions.